# Is using a variable based on near infrared radiation to predict a variable based on thermal infrared a circular exercise?

Tags: radiation, infrared-radiation

I am creating a model which aims to predict a Land Surface Temperature related variable (from satellite thermal infrared measurements) which uses a vegetation related variable (created using satellite near infrared, red and blue light measurements).

I have had a comment that this is a circular exercise as they both use infrared radiation in their derivation. I can see how the two are related but as they are different wavelength ranges, one dealing with heat and one with light, I am struggling to understand this comment and cannot find anything relating to it online, is this concept physically sound?

Thank you for any help in understanding!

Comment: Doesn't sound circular to me.

Comment: Who commented, under what circumstances? Certainly in the description of the model you should have good clear arguments as to why the logic is not circular. In particular, showing that the satellite thermal IR measurements are at different wavelengths than the other measurements would be a good start. Sounds more like a presentation issue than a physics issue?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advice - this is very reassuring and as pointed out, it appears I need to give more explanation into why the two measurements differ (the comment was at a conference poster presentation of my work).